# Facebook- Post To Page Wall I Own (Admin)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok, there are alot of similar questions here which I have found to be of aid, but nothing clear enough for me to work with(probably because it is my first time integrating facebook in my apps).

I have read this: 
[Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages?rq=1) 
and this 
[post as page on facebook page wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971721/post-as-page-on-facebook-page-wall)
but none of them describe the process which they have gone through to setup it all up.

I want to allow multiple users to post to a Facebook page I own, possibly at the same time, which means that I do not want the users to require logging in in order to post on the wall through the application.

What I understand:

1. I believe that this must be server side script for it to work as I
   need it to.
2. I have a FB app set up, which I know I require it.
3. I read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

What I don't understand:

Which type of access token do I need ? An App Access token, or a Page Access token ? 
Whatever the answer, how should I go about getting the token ? Are there multiple/different ways of doing it? As i have found several answers with different instructions, such as obtaining it on the fly using the HTTP get request such as

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials
```

or getting it by visiting : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/AppID/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts

So Which is it? I am confused. Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated

NB: Development is done using cakePHP.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I have mentioned the post and pointed out that it is very similar to what I need but not quite clear!Actually it is the reason why I am asking this question. As both answers are different. One stating you need App access token, other the page access token

Comment: _“I want to allow multiple users to post to a Facebook page I own, possibly at the same time, which means that I do not want the users to require logging in in order to post on the wall through the application.”_ – then your only option is to have them post _as_ the page )is that really what you want?). If so, then yes, you will have to get a page access token. And one way of how to do that is described in the other answer already. Other ways are described in the FB documentation.

Comment: If this users is not the page admin, you must grant user access token of each user and using multiple User Access Token to post on their behalf.

Comment: @CBroe I am already getting the page access token using one of the methods described(from the graph explorer), but the problem is that I am hardcoding that access token, but will eventually expire once the user logs out of fb. How can I dealt with that? Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extendingpagetokens